# axios / jest - unabled to perform a call request (TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined)

Tags: axios, jestjs

I'm struggling to perform a test with jest concerning an axios api call

here is my API call, that works perfectly within my program

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import crypto from 'crypto';
import { prop } from 'ramda';

const baseUrl = 'http://gateway.marvel.com:80';
const uri = '/v1/public/characters';
const charactersUrl = baseUrl + uri;

const timestamp = [Math.round(+new Date() / 1000)];
const privateApi = 'XXX';
const publicApi = 'XXX';

const concatenatedString = timestamp.concat(privateApi, publicApi).join('');

const hash = crypto.createHash('md5').update(`${concatenatedString}`).digest('hex');

const charactersApi = () =>
  axios
    .get(charactersUrl, {
      params: {
        ts: timestamp,
        apikey: publicApi,
        hash,
      },
    })
    .then(prop('data'));

export default charactersApi;
```

When I'm trying to test it, that way:

```js
import axiosMock from 'axios';
import charactersApi from '../marvelApi';

jest.mock('axios', () => ({
  get: jest.fn(),
}));

describe('tools | marvelApi', () => {
  const piece = { name: '3D-MAN' };
  axiosMock.get.mockResolvedValueOnce({ data: piece });

  it('should get the character', () => {
    return charactersApi().then(elem => {
      expect(elem.name).toEqual('3D-MAN');
    });
  });
});
```

I get the following message from jest

```sh
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

      16 |
      17 | const charactersApi = () =>
    > 18 |   axios
         |   ^
      19 |     .get(charactersUrl, {
      20 |       params: {
      21 |         ts: timestamp,

      at charactersApi (src/tools/marvelApi.js:18:3)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/tools/tests/marvelApi.test.js:13:12)
```

**What I have tried**

- A common error is to forget the return statement within the function that contain the request API, in my case it's done correctly (first piece of code -> charactersApi()) [source1](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/javascript-promise-typeerror:-cannot-read-then-of-undefined), [source2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50467805/jest-test-gives-an-error-typeerror-cannot-read-property-then-of-undefined)
- I also tried to return a Promise from the mocked Axios as I have seen on another SO ticket

```js
jest.mock('axios', () => ({
  get: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve()),
}));
```

I think my axios mock is not correct, because the struggle comes from the test while the production version work well

Any thoughts ?

Comment: Don't ever expose your api keys! I've already removed it for you.

Comment: thank you, I have partially remove the private key at start, I thought it was enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can spy on the "axios.get" calls and resolve them to a fixed (mocked) value:

```js
/**
 * @jest-environment jsdom
 */
const axios = require('axios')

beforeAll(() => {
  jest.spyOn(axios, 'get').mockImplementation()
})

afterAll(() => {
  jest.restoreAllMocks()
})

it('returns the mocked response', async () => {
  axios.get.mockResolvedValue({ data: 'foo' })
  const res = await axios.get('https://api.github.com')
  expect(res).toEqual({ data: 'foo' })
})
```

You shouldn't use `jest.mock` because it mocks a *module* that your imported code may be using. As far as I know, it doesn't affect the current module's imports (and you import `axios` as a part of your test).

### Recommended solution

I strongly discourage you from spying/mocking `axios` directly. See my argumentation below.

1. You're mocking implementation details of `axios`. In other words, you take the `axios.get` function and throw it away, alongside any internal logic it may have, and replace it with a hard mock. This means your test no longer uses `axios`, instead it uses an emptied mocked shell of `axios`. This makes your test different from your actual code, which, in turn, decreases the confidence such a test gives you.
2. You're coupling your mocks with a specific request client (axios). Such an approach is not a long-term investment, as you're writing axios-specific mocks. You can't reuse such mocks for requests made by other clients (i.e. `window.fetch`, Apollo, etc.), because they have their own implementation details (i.e. `window.fetch` has no `.get()` to spy on), which only encourages you to write more implementation-specific logic in tests.

> You can learn more about the disadvantages of direct mocking of request clients in the [Stop mocking fetch](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/stop-mocking-fetch/) article by Kent C. Dodds. It uses `window.fetch` mocks as an example, but you may replace it with `ANY_REQUEST_CLIENT` when reading.

I highly recommend using tools like [Mock Service Worker](https://mswjs.io) (MSW) that will encourage you to write abstracted mocks that don't rely on any request clients (you can use them no matter how your tested code makes a request) and can even be reused across different testing levels (the same mocks for Jest, Storybook, or Cypress).

Here's how your test would look like with MSW:

```js
import { rest } from 'msw'
import { setupServer } from 'msw/node'
import charactersApi from '../marvelApi';

const server = setupServer(
  rest.get('http://gateway.marvel.com:80/v1/public/characters', (req, res, ctx) => {
    return res(ctx.json({
      data: {
        name: '3D-MAN'
      }
    }))
  })
)

beforeAll(() => server.listen()
afterAll(() => server.close())

describe('tools | marvelApi', () => {
  it('should get the character', () => {
    return charactersApi().then(elem => {
      expect(elem.name).toEqual('3D-MAN')
    })
  })
})
```

Notice how there are no details about *how* the request is made, only *which* request to intercept and mock its response.

**You can follow a detailed tutorial on how to [Get started with MSW](https://mswjs.io/docs/getting-started/install)**. There's also a [great video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=76yEzm07Kfk) on API mocking and what problems MSW solves.

---

Comment: I learnt a lot with your post, from now I'm gonna div deeply into MSW
Thanks to you @kettanaito

Comment: I have seen the video you linked. it's pretty clear, however I have the following question:
In my case, the success of the api call is made thanks to en API key (that is used to authenticate me), do you agree if I said that msw is not consistent of the API key if it valid or no. In other word, the test could be a fail in production because the API key isn't correct where as the test will be a success

Comment: The API key validity is not the concern of the integration test (which you're illustrating in your question). I'd argue that it isn't the concern for an E2E test either, but this is debatable. That is _not_ a bad thing, though. Establishing clear testing boundaries is what makes focused tests.

Comment: Since it's often a third-party system that validates API keys, their validity lies outside of your application's code. You shouldn't be testing a third-party system's operability in any way, apart from your interactions with that system. I'd recommend taking API key validity into account in E2E/canary tests (i.e. perform actual authorization, etc.).

Comment: understood, thank you for this explanation